# C++ indicate Palindrome

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm pretty new to coding in C++ and need your help. In the code below I want to check for Parlindrome and show the reversed text. So if I run this code, it displays the right reversed words, but dont return them true if checked for parlindrome.

The console shows:
madam0
ada0
ecalevol0

Why the return is always 0?

Thanks for your help!

```
#include <iostream>

// Define is_palindrome() here:

bool is_palindrome(std::string text) {
  std::string text_reversed;

  for(int i = text.length(); i >= 0; i-- ) {
    text_reversed += text[i];
    std::cout << text[i];
  }

  if (text_reversed == text) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

int main() {
  
  std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("ada") << "\n";
  std::cout << is_palindrome("lovelace") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings because this should be VTC'd as typo.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry but that argument makes no sense. Here's why: (a) You didn't VTC at all. (b) If it's off-topic, it shouldn't be answered _at all_. (c) If it's answered, it goes in the answer section. Hence the name. So it can be peer reviewed. Hover your mouse over the "add a comment" link: it says _avoid answering questions in comments_. Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: offtopic: which version do you prefer: `if (condition) return true; else return false;` or equivalent: `return condition;`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `i` starts at `text.length()`, not `text.length() - 1`.

So, your first `text[i]` is a null byte (yes, even for `std::string`, this is guaranteed).

Thus the first character of `text_reversed` is a "hidden" character that was not present in `text`, and the two will never match.

Comment: Thanks! So it makes sense now

Comment: "So, your first text[i] is a null **pointer**" - there are no pointers here, it is a null byte (sometimes known as `NUL`). And how would printing the whole reversed string help? The `NUL` would still be invisible.

Comment: @BoBTFish _"it is a null byte"_ Oops, good spot. _"And how would printing the whole reversed string help? The NUL would still be invisible."_ Hmm yeah also fair - I was imagining that streaming a single null were defined to do nothing, but that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
std::string reversed_string(const std::string& s)
{
    return {s.rbegin(), s.rend()};
}

bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size() / 2, s.rbegin());
}
```

Documentation of [std::equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) has example of `is_palindrome`

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problems there are `i>=0` and `text[i]`. It should be `i>0` and `text[i-1]`.

And please simplify that return statement.

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_palindrome(std::string text) {

  std::string text_reversed = "";

  for(int i = text.length(); i > 0; i-- ) {
    text_reversed += text[i-1];
  }
  std::cout << text_reversed <<std::endl;
  std::cout << text <<std::endl;

  return text == text_reversed;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << is_palindrome("ada") << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << is_palindrome("lovelace") << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So `text.compare();` checks if 2 variables are the same and returns true or false?

Comment: `compare` returns an `int` whose sign you must check, not a `bool`. `operator ==` was fine there.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I had it with == but then tried using .compare(), realize it didn't work but forgot to revert the changes :(